# $R=\begin{pmatrix} K & K\\ 0 & K \end{pmatrix}$. Show that $\text{End}_R(eR)$ is a field even though $eR$ is not an irreducible $R$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

**Question:** Let $K$ be a field and let $R\subset M_2(K)$ be given by $R=\begin{pmatrix}
K & K\\
0 & K
\end{pmatrix}$.  If $e=e_{1,1}$, show that $\text{End}_R(eR)$ is a field even though $eR$ is not an irreducible $R$-module.

**My Thoughts:** I am assuming that $e$ is an idempotent in $R$, so I am trying to use Lemma $4.3$ from Passman's "A Course in Ring Theory" (lemma below).  I know the only maximal ideals correspond to the maximal ideals of $K\times K$, and so the only maximal ideals of $R$ are $\begin{pmatrix}
K & K\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & K\\
0 & K
\end{pmatrix}$.... I am not quite sure if this would help me, but I am wondering if I could maybe avoid appealing to the lemma below.   Or, maybe it would be best to use the lemma below, I am just not quite seeing how..

Lemma $4.3$: Let $e, f$ be idempotents in a ring (with unity) $R$.  Then,

1. If $V$ is an $R$-module, then Hom$_R(eR,V)\cong Ve$.  In particular, Hom$_R(eR,fR)\cong fRe$.
2. If $e\neq 0$, then End$_R(eR)$ is ring isomorphic to $eRe$ acting by left multiplication.
3. If $F$ is a free $R$-module of rank $n$, then End$_R(F)\cong M_n(R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming that  is an idempotent in

Uhh, there's no need to assume. How about you just multiply $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ by itself and confirm it.

> I am trying to use Lemma $4.3$ from Passman's "A Course in Ring Theory" (lemma below).

Well that's good because #2 tells you it is a field immediately.

> I know the only maximal ideals correspond to the maximal ideals of $×$ [...]  I am not quite sure if this would help me

Rest assured: it does not help you.

Only thing left is to demonstrate that it has a nontrivial submodule. But given that $\begin{bmatrix}0 & K \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is an ideal of $R$ that should point you to a nontrivial submodul right away. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, I see!  And $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & K \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a nontrivial submodule of $R$ since the right ideals of the right regular module are the submodules of R... I believe.

Comment: @User7238 Yeah but you are not looking for a nontrivial submodule of $R$. You're looking for a nontrivial submodule of $eR$.

Comment: Ah, okay, so if I multiply $e$ on the left to an element in that ideal, then I will get a matrix with nonzero entry in row $1$, column $2$, where that entry is in $K$.  Thus getting a nontrivial submodule of $eR$, right?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Comment: ah, okay, thank you!  I really do appreciate your help!